# Нужно не выводить, а возвращать данные в curl php

Tags: php, curl

На первом сайте site1/script.php:

```
echo $a=5;
```

На втором сайте site2/script.php:

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://site1/script.php");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0); 
echo $outputprog=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Почему скрипт `site2/script.php` выводит на экран `5`, если указан `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);`?

Если в `site1/script.php` убрать `echo` то совсем ничего не выводит, даже через `var_dump`.

Главный вопрос: как возвращать значение переменной `$a` из сайта `site1/script.php` в сайт `site2/script.php` без вывода на экран?

Comment: как вариант на первом скрипте вывести `echo '$a = 5;';`  а на втором выполнить такой код `eval(curl_exec($ch));` и тогда можно выводить `echo $a;` 
и да без вывода никак.

Answer (score 2):

Вы же сами выводите результат на экран `echo $outputprog=curl_exec($ch);`

Уберите `echo` и оставьте `$outputprog=curl_exec($ch);`. Переменная `$outputprog` будет хранить '5'.

Comment: @Alex затупил. Поправил.

Comment: возможно стоит немного изменить: уберите `echo` и оставьте `$outputprog=curl_exec($ch);`, чтобы по смыслу было более понятно.